# Table layout in HTML

Tags: html, html-table

I'm trying to make a table in HTML and i need help.
Here's a rough drawing:

[Drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3OxX.png)

Can it be done?

Comment: Yes, it's 100% possible. Good luck :)

Comment: You're asking  as if it was something so special that has never been done before. Show us what you tried already and explain what issues you're having

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
td {border:1px solid black}
table {border:1px solid black}
```

```html
<table ><tr><td>foo</td><td rowspan=2>picture</td></tr><tr><td>bar</td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

problems like this can be solved by using colspan or rowspan.
for example you probably need something like:

```
<table border=1><tr><td>headline 1</td><td rowspan=2>image</td>
<tr><td>headline2</td></tr></table>
```

Seems to work for me.